# How to process elements from other classes in java

Tags: java

I'll be honest I cant correctly describe in one sentence what I want but am pretty sure it can be done. Pardon me but I am a still a rookie with java

I am writing a simple java program with a GUI in java (Netbeans) and have many buttons and similar elements that do the same thing just on another button or element, lets say a button removes a line from a jtable, now I have 7 jpanels where i do the same think and find it inefficient that i must rewrite the code every time.

Basically what I want to do is make a class or function where I send the elements that I want to be processed and apply the code to them.
Lets say this:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable5.getModel();
model.removeRow(jTable5.getSelectedRow());
jTable5.remove(jTable5.getSelectedRow());
jTable5.revalidate();
```

Rather than saying jTable5 i want a template function/class where i just pass the name of the element. Is such a thing possible?

And I am really sorry for this noobish question, as really I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Read the description twice, still don't the question. Could you please put more effort into describing the scenario. Perhaps show us what code is getting duplicated.

Comment: @SamiFarhat sorry I really could't describe quite right what I wanted but Gops AB understood my _stupid_ question. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the following way you can apply your logic to all of your jTables just by iterating.

```
void func(Object jTable) { 
 //YOURCLASS jTable5 = (YOURCLASS) jTable;
 JTable jTable5 = (JTable) jTable;
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable5.getModel();
 model.removeRow(jTable5.getSelectedRow());
 jTable5.remove(jTable5.getSelectedRow());
 jTable5.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for understaing my problem, I am aware that my question was unclear but this was precisely what I was asking for!
Thank you!